# Confirming that shell is running on an Amazon WorkSpace

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-linux, amazon-linux-2, amazon-workspaces

I am currently writing a number of shell scripts which will run both on an Amazon Workspaces Linux instance and elsewhere on other Linux hosts (e.g. Amazon Linux EC2 instances).

I would like to have certain Bash variable values configured differently depending on whether or not a given script is being run on a WorkSpaces instance.

Given this, I was wondering if there is a way of checking at the OS level whether the host is an Amazon WorkSpace or not?

Comment: Maybe there is something relevant in [instance metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html)?

Comment: I had thought about this but in this case the instance metadata isn't readable due to firewall restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

Although possibly not fail proof, one method of identifying whether a Linux host is one of the Amazon Linux WorkSpaces hosts is to look for the presence of the `/usr/share/icons/amazon-workspaces` directory where the icon assets for MATE window manager theme are stored.